# Using an icon instead of bullet points in a list

Tags: java, css, angularjs, list, icons

I have an Angular directive that I've made which spits out a list that i am displaying. What i want to do is use an icon instead of the bullet point..i kind of have it working but currently the icon shows up above the list items on each line. i would prefer not to use much css bc i am using this as a directive in an angular app..

Here is what I have tried so far...

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="errors.length > 1">
    <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="err in errors">
        <i class="alert-icon-danger alert-icon"></i><li ng-bind="err"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want to use CSS, as it is the best solution...

Anyway, here is how it can be easily done (using Bootstrap):

```
.glyphi-bullet li:before {
    content: "\e080";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

---

```css
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        
.custom-bullet li {
    display: block;
}

.custom-bullet li:before
{
    /*Using a Bootstrap glyphicon as the bullet point*/
    content: "\e080";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom-bullet">
    <li>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam.</li>
    <li>Cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia.</li>
    <li>Qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
</ul>
```

## [Demo in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8svtgxt/)

Comment: i'm using htis in a directive(angularjs) and didnt really want to set up the css to work with the directive...but i guess you're right haha i should just set up the css to work with it

Comment: @jeremy As I don't see your directive, I can't really advice you more. But I don't see any case where it could be clearer to set the CSS in a directive (more complicated, less readable). :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "display: inline" to your elements.